# Is using shared_ptr after reset undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, undefined-behavior

I have this test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout<<"A Constructor\n";
    }

    ~A(){
        std::cout<<"A Destructor\n";
    }

    void show()
    {
        std::cout<<"A::show()"<<'\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto p1 = std::make_shared<A>();
    // Relinquishes ownership of p1 on the object
    // and pointer becomes NULL
    p1.reset();
    std::cout<<p1.get()<<'\n';
    std::cout<<p1.use_count()<<'\n';
    p1->show();
    return 0;
}
```

Which yields this output:

```
A Constructor
A Destructor
0
0
A::show()
```

I ran this via gdb and saw:

```
:
:
(gdb) s
A::show (this=0x0) at so.cpp:18
18              std::cout<<"A::show()"<<'\n';
(gdb) s
A::show()
:
```

The line `A::show (this=0x0) at so.cpp:18` indicates that the underlying resource is null. I looked at [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625401/obejct-accessable-with-native-ptr-after-shared-ptrreset) question but there the raw pointer was being used to invoke the member function. Is this case too similar to the one in that question since `p1->show()` too should be equivalent to something like `p1.get()->show();`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct, this is fundamentally the same thing as in the question you linked: The `A` instance is deleted when you call `reset()`, and accessing it afterwards is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a data member to the class and you can see visually undefined behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout<<"A Constructor\n";
    }

    ~A(){
        std::cout<<"A Destructor\n";
    }

    void show()
    {
        std::cout<<"A::show()"<<'\n';
        ++x;
    }

    int x = 0;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> p1(new A);
    // Relinquishes ownership of p1 on the object
    // and pointer becomes NULL
    p1.reset();
    std::cout<<p1.get()<<'\n';
    std::cout<<p1.use_count()<<'\n';
    p1->show();
    return 0;
}
```

For example at run-time an error like this

```
Runtime error #stdin #stdout 0s 4280KB
```

can be shown.

That is the null-pointer was used to access the data member.